# android.view.InflateException: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-navigation-view

В Android Studio создал проект по шаблону Navigation Drawer Activity при отладке вылетает ошибка в onCreate MainActivity:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
```

В xml nav_view:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />
```

nav_header_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/logo_act"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/nav_header_vertical_spacing"
        android:text="Flower Deliver"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Just Deliver It" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Чем это вызвано? 
Если minSdk = 15
И Sdk устройства = 15

Comment: Попробуйте пересобрать проект/ отключить InstantRun/удалить меню/хедер из разметки

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Действительно, удалил хедер - заработало. Как сделать проект рабочим с хедером?

Comment: У вас что-то не то в разметке хедера. К сожалению в сообщении об ошибке подробностей вы получить никак не сможете. Так что надо методом тыка вырезать всё подряд (атрибуты разные разметки) и смотреть когда заработает